# Tracking Microsoft 365 Outlook Email to SQL Server

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, microsoft-exchange

I want to fetch the details from my outlook mailbox but don't have the Microsoft exchange server. I only have cloud-based services.

I tried to use the below-given code but that is an exchange server API solution. The second method is to open the outlook app and then accessing the mailbox but doesn't want this solution.

---

```
try
{
       'Mailbox credentials'
       string emailAddress = AppSettings.Office365EmailAddress;
       string password = AppSettings.Office365Password;
    
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
       CertificateValidationCallBack;
       ExchangeService service = new 
       ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
                  
       service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(emailAddress, password);
       service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
       service.PreAuthenticate = true;
       service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, 
       emailAddress);
       ItemView view = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
       FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, 
       SetFilter(), view);
    
       DataTable dtEmails = GenerateEmailDataTable();
       DataRow dr = dtEmails.NewRow();
                   
       foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
       {
         if (item.Subject != null)
            {
               Match match = Regex.Match(item.Subject.ToString(), regJMSNumber);
               if (match != null)
                   {
                     dr["EmailTo"] = item.DisplayTo.ToString();
                     dr["EmailFrom"] = item.DisplayTo.ToString();
                     dr["EmailCC"] = item.DisplayCc.ToString();
                     dr["EmailBCC"] = item.DisplayTo.ToString();
                     dr["EmailSubject"] = item.Subject.ToString();
                     dr["EmailBody"] = item.Body.ToString();
                     dr["CreatedOn"] = item.Subject.ToString();
                     dr["IsActive"] = true;
                  }
                  else
                   {
                      Console.WriteLine("Subject Not Match");
                   }
              }
                    }
                }
    
                'Error handler.'
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught: ", e);
                }
                finally
                {
                   
                }
```

---

Another approach is the Power Automate option but I want to do it programmatically.
Used https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx API.
When I am using EWS (exchange API), the application throwing a **401 Unauthorised requests failed exception.**

Please tell me any other way to track the outlook emails with all details like `EmailTo`, `EmailSent`, `EmailSubject`, `EmailBody`, `EmailCC`, `EmailBCC`, and all the trailing messages.

Comment: By "I only have cloud-based services", do you mean you are connecting to an Office 365 mailbox? It is an Exchange server and EWS works just fine.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I asked my organization's administrator he told me we don't have an on-premise exchange server. when I am using the 'Exchange.asmx' API it is throwing exception 401 Unauthorised, request failed

Comment: If you are using Office 365 (whcih is still Exchange), most likely Basic Authentication is disabled and you need to use OAuth2.